# Should I use beginTransaction() and endTransaction() both in insert() and bulkInsert()?

Tags: android, performance, android-sqlite, android-contentprovider, bulkinsert

I am working on an Android application in which I am using Content Provider. I am overriding the **insert()** and **bulkInsert()** methods.

I will use **insert()** and **bulkInsert()** in different scenarios. 
I know **bulkInsert()** uses **insert()** internally.

I need the transactions to be atomic.   Should I use **beginTransaction()** and **endTransaction()** in *both* **insert** and **bulkInsert**?

Comment: Fix misspellings and grammar.  Improve formatting.

Comment: @Prune : Kindly let me know where to fix spelling, grammar and formatting

Comment: Ah!  That's a communication problem.  My comment is the logged comment when I edited your question.  You don't need to fix anything more.  The Stack Overflow editing software asks for "what did this guy do to my posting"; it's not aimed directly at you.  I'll try to remember this in the future.

Answer (score 0):

When you are inserting bulk data it's very important that you use

```
BeginTransaction();
SetTransactionSuccessful();
EndTransaction();
```

Because if you don't do that the SQLite itself will wrap every query with an implicit transaction. By using BeginTransaction() and EndTransaction() you can improve the performance. For detail read https://medium.com/@JasonWyatt/squeezing-performance-from-sqlite-insertions-971aff98eef2

When you are using only one record you can ignore BeginTransaction() and EndTransaction().

Similar post 
[beginTransaction(), endTransaction(), and setTransactionSuccessful(). What exactly do they do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16564000/begintransaction-endtransaction-and-settransactionsuccessful-what-exact)